# SQL search with special characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a table that contains names that are in German and have special characters in them like: ä, ö, ü, etc. This is how I search that table:

```
SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE users.name LIKE '%sch%' LIMIT 8
```

Let say that we have a user named `"Schön"` and someone types in search `"Schon"` . The above code will return 0 rows since `ö != o`.

What is the best practice when handling special characters like this? I know that I could replace characters but that's just pointless.

Comment: try select ö = o in mysql you will get 1 because its same for mysql

Comment: depens what charset collision is being used if `ö = o` is equal or not  @JayShankarGupta .. i think `utf8_unicode_ci` would be the collision John needs.

Comment: What about other languages like `č`, `é`, `đ`, ...? Also I tried with `utf8_unicode_ci` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- _the column definition makes a big difference_.

Answer (score 1):

The query will fail to return any names that do not contain `sch`; it has nothing to do with `o` or `ö`.

Apparently your *collation* does not do case folding, or else the `Sch` in `Schön` would have been caught by `LIKE '%sch%'`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`.  You should find that the collation for `name` is `..._bin`.  This says `S` != `s` *and* `ö` != `o`.